# How to print doc using Airprinter using objective-C?

Tags: ios, ipad, printing

I am working on print functionality in my iOS app.I want my app print doc using Air-printer.is it need to Apple AirPort Base Station.Please anybody suggest me.
Thanks.

Comment: For testing purposes, the iOS Simulator can launch Printer Simulator.  Your iOS app should be able to find the Printer Simulator and print to it.

Comment: There is also software you can install on a PC or Mac that will act as an AirPrint bridge between your iOS device and a non-AirPrint printer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the current iOS SDK, you can only print to [AirPrint](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4356).